# Are MapBox mobile SDK (iOS, Android) able to show raster tiles from binary images on memory?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

I want to use MapBox mobile SDK (iOS, Android).
Actually I use them from Xamarin, but Xamarin SDK is just wrapper of Obj-C/Java SDKs, so I think there are no differences.

What I want to do is, showing raster tile maps from binary images on memory.
In my app, I have tile image data as binary in memory, like NSData or byte, so I show them on map as web Mercator raster tiles.

I can't find such interface on MapBox SDK's document.

Anyone know whether MapBox SDK can raster tiles from binary image on memory or not?

Answer (score 1):

MapBox have a plan to implement local interface:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/7471